# запрос в БД (SELECT SUM) ничего не выводит, в чем ошибка?

Tags: php, sql

Объясните в чем может быть ошибка? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]запрос ничего не выводит

```
$rait = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rait) FROM table_reviews");
$rait = mysql_fetch_array($rait);
echo $rait['rait'];
```

Comment: понял, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было указать `AS 'rait'`

```
$rait = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rait) AS 'rait' FROM table_reviews");
$rait = mysql_fetch_array($rait);
echo $rait['rait'];
```